# How to Range Slider and Selector with Plotly-Dash

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to recreate this Plotly [example](https://plot.ly/python/range-slider/) with Dash, but I cannot get the buttons and the range slider. Does anyone know how I can do this?

That's what I tried:

```
traces =[{
            'x':df.index,
            'y':df.level,
            'type': 'scatter',
            'mode': 'lines',
            'name': 'a_level'
    }]
    graphs.append(dcc.Graph(
        id='a_level',
        figure={
            'data': traces,
            'layout': {
                    'type': 'date',
                    'rangeslider': {'visible':True},
                    'margin': {'b': 0, 'r': 10, 'l': 60, 't': 0}
            }
        }
    )
```

Comment: Please add the code you are using to the question. The code in the URL might change.

Comment: It's an example on Plotly website (Range Slider and Selector in Python) if you click on the link you can see the code. I'm trying to make sth. like that with Dash.

Comment: Without the code which does not work it is impossible to guess the correct solution.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters I edit the question and add my code, do you know how I can get the ragerslider with scatter plot in dash?

Answer (score 3):

The `RangeSlider` is a [Dash Core Component](https://plot.ly/dash/dash-core-components), it's not an attribute of `Graph` (which is also a Dash Core Component).

Here is a simple app layout:

```
import dash_core_components as dcc

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1('My Dash App'),
    html.Div(
        [
            html.Label('From 2007 to 2017', id='time-range-label'),
            dcc.RangeSlider(
                id='year_slider',
                min=1991,
                max=2017,
                value=[2007, 2017]
            ),
        ],
        style={'margin-top': '20'}
    ), 
    html.Hr(),
    dcc.Graph(id='my-graph')
])
```

Now you just have to define a callback that gets called every time the value of the `RangeSlider` changes. This is the `Input` that causes `_update_graph` to get called.
You could have multiple inputs (e.g. a `Dropdown`, another `RangeSlider`, etc).

The `Output` is always a single one. In this example it's the `figure` attribute of the `Graph` component.

```
# the value of RangeSlider causes Graph to update
@app.callback(
    output=Output('my-graph', 'figure'),
    inputs=[Input('year_slider', 'value')]
    )
def _update_graph(year_range):
    date_start = '{}-01-01'.format(year_range[0])
    date_end = '{}-12-31'.format(year_range[1])
    # etc...
```

A Dash Core Component could cause several components to update. For example, a `RangeSlider` could cause a `Label` to change.

```
# the value of RangeSlider causes Label to update
@app.callback(
    output=Output('time-range-label', 'children'),
    inputs=[Input('year_slider', 'value')]
    )
def _update_time_range_label(year_range):
    return 'From {} to {}'.format(year_range[0], year_range[1])
```

Comment: how would the `rangeslider` objects change in order to represent all days between two dates? I am not sure range slider can accept `datetime` objects?
I have set:
`date_range = pd.date_range(start='1989-5-1',end='1989-9-30',freq='D')`
and
`dcc.RangeSlider(id = 'DateTimeSlider',
updatemode = 'mouseup',
min = date_range.min(),
max = date_range.max(),
step='D',
value = [date_range.min(), date_range.max()],
)`

Comment: I tried running what you have with the headers and footers added and I see the slider and a blank graph. Can you provide a working script with your solution?

Answer (score 3):

`rangeslider` is a property of `xaxis`.

I use something like this:

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css'])
    app.layout = html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(
            id='bar_plot',
            figure=go.Figure(
                data=area,
                layout=go.Layout(
                    xaxis={
                        'rangeslider': {'visible':True},
                        'rangeselector': {'visible':True, 'buttons':[{'step':'all'}, {'step':'day'}, {'step':'hour'}]}
                    },
                )))
    ])
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for the question. Additionally, if you want to tie a callback to the rangeslider, the property to use is `relayoutData`. For example, `INPUT('bar_plot','relayoutData')` will be a dictionary with and `xaxis.range` key if the rangeslider is used.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this (with a df that has datetimeindex):

## Function

```
def get__marks(f):

dates = {}
for z in f.index:
    dates[f.index.get_loc(z)] = {}
    dates[f.index.get_loc(z)] = str(z.month) + "-" + str(z.day)

return j
```

## App Layout

```
dcc.RangeSlider(
    id='range-slider',
    updatemode='mouseup',
    min=0,
    max=len(df.index) - 1,
    count=1,
    step=1,
    value=[0, len(df.index) - 1],
    marks=get_marks(df),
)
```