# Date slider with Plotly Dash does not work

Tags: python, dashboard, plotly-dash

I am trying to build a dash app with a datetime slider, but the following code does not work - the url displays "Error loading layout". Is there something wrong with my code, or are there any tricks needed to build a slider on datetime objects? Reproducible code follows:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import datetime

base = datetime.datetime.today()
date_list = [base - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, 10)]

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Label('Slider'),
    dcc.RangeSlider(min=min(date_list), 
                    max=max(date_list), 
                    value=min(date_list))
    ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Comment: To whoever downvoted it would be great if you could explain why - thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Plotly-Dash does currently **not support datetime objects**.

A solution for you problem is to described in my answer to an other question [Plotly datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49371248/plotly-dash-has-unknown-issue-and-creates-error-loading-dependencies-by-using/51003812#51003812)

---

One possible solution is to use two different arguments at the initialization:

- value
- marks

Example by using pandas for timestamp generation:

Needed imports:

```
import pandas as pd
import time
```

Some needed functions:

```
daterange = pd.date_range(start='2017',end='2018',freq='W')

def unixTimeMillis(dt):
    ''' Convert datetime to unix timestamp '''
    return int(time.mktime(dt.timetuple()))

def unixToDatetime(unix):
    ''' Convert unix timestamp to datetime. '''
    return pd.to_datetime(unix,unit='s')

def getMarks(start, end, Nth=100):
    ''' Returns the marks for labeling. 
        Every Nth value will be used.
    '''

    result = {}
    for i, date in enumerate(daterange):
        if(i%Nth == 1):
            # Append value to dict
            result[unixTimeMillis(date)] = str(date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

    return result
```

For the RangeSlider object you can initialize it like this:

```
dcc.RangeSlider(
                id='year_slider',
                min = unixTimeMillis(daterange.min()),
                max = unixTimeMillis(daterange.max()),
                value = [unixTimeMillis(daterange.min()),
                         unixTimeMillis(daterange.max())],
                marks=getMarks(daterange.min(),
                            daterange.max())
            )
```

Comment: Strangely, the keys must be cast as integers as well, not floats. Nice work. https://github.com/plotly/dash-core-components/issues/159

Answer (score 2):

This should definitely work and is much easier than any other solution

```
marks = {int(i):str(j) for i,j in zip(range(len(df.years)), df[“years”])}
```

And then you can mimic the same in the functional callbacks to update the values by dictionary keys.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation, why not try just the regular slider `dcc.Slider`. You can check the example at the bottom of the documentation: https://dash.plot.ly/getting-started#dash-app-layout.

EDIT: Added code example from the documentation.

You can add this as an element to your list, `hmtl.Div`.

```
html.Label('Slider'),
    dcc.Slider(
        min=0,
        max=9,
        marks={i: 'Label {}'.format(i) if i == 1 else str(i) for i in range(1, 6)},
        value=5,
    ),
```

Comment: Tried dcc.Slider, it does not make a difference. The problem seems to be elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

What are you index units? Pandas' datetime or simply numbers?

I tried doing a little bit of debugging:

```
app.layout = html.Div([dcc.RangeSlider(id='my-slider',
                                       min=1,
                                       max=5,
                                       step=1,
                                       # value=2,
                                       ),
                       html.H1(id='product')])
```

It turns out that if I set the value (so uncomment `value=2`), it breaks. 
It would be good if you could try without the `value` argument.

EDIT:
**The `value` argument needs to be a list** (the *range*...). Setting `value=[2,3]`works. This might solve your problem.

Comment: I edited the number to provide reproducible datetimes. Having a list of values does not make a difference. It seems like the issue is related to having datetimes instead of float/int (?)

Comment: Yes, I think the issue comes from the fact that you are using datetimes rather than int/floats. See https://community.plot.ly/t/solved-has-anyone-made-a-date-range-slider/6531/8

Comment: I am surprised that they don't support that yet though, because they do support it for the graphs' rangesliders

Comment: Indeed. The plotly forum clearly isn't as good as StackOverflow - that example is hard to replicate. I will try though.

Answer (score 0):

Just add-on.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, datetime, date

dates = ['03-02-2021', '03-03-2021', '03-04-2021', '03-05-2021', '03-06-2021', '03-07-2021']
mytotaldates = {i:datetime.strptime(x, "%m-%d-%Y").date() for i,x in enumerate(dates)}


a = (list(mytotaldates.keys()))

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(children=[   
    dcc.Slider(
        id='Dateslider',
        min=a[0],
        max=a[-1],
        marks=mytotaldates,
        value=a[-1],
    ),
    html.Div(id='OutputContainer')
])


@app.callback(
    Output('OutputContainer', 'children'),
    [Input('Dateslider', 'value')])
def rangerselection(val):
    val = mytotaldates[val]
    return f'Selected Date: {val}'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False, use_reloader=True)
```