# How do I auto-adjust the y-axis when the x-axis changes in a plotly chart?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard

I have a plotly chart that uses a range selector that looks like this-

```
import datetime
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
import plotly
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from pyorbital.orbital import Orbital
satellite = Orbital('TERRA')

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    html.Div([
        html.H4('TERRA Satellite Live Feed'),
        html.Div(id='live-update-text'),
        dcc.Graph(id='live-update-graph'),
        dcc.Interval(
            id='interval-component',
            interval=1*1000, # in milliseconds
            n_intervals=0
        )
    ])
)


@app.callback(Output('live-update-text', 'children'),
              Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'))
def update_metrics(n):
    lon, lat, alt = satellite.get_lonlatalt(datetime.datetime.now())
    style = {'padding': '5px', 'fontSize': '16px'}
    return [
        html.Span('Longitude: {0:.2f}'.format(lon), style=style),
        html.Span('Latitude: {0:.2f}'.format(lat), style=style),
        html.Span('Altitude: {0:0.2f}'.format(alt), style=style)
    ]


# Multiple components can update everytime interval gets fired.
@app.callback(Output('live-update-graph', 'figure'),
              Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'))
def update_graph_live(n):
    satellite = Orbital('TERRA')
    data = {
        'time': [],
        'Latitude': [],
        'Longitude': [],
        'Altitude': []
    }

    # Collect some data
    for i in range(180):
        time = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=i*20)
        lon, lat, alt = satellite.get_lonlatalt(
            time
        )
        data['Longitude'].append(lon)
        data['Latitude'].append(lat)
        data['Altitude'].append(alt)
        data['time'].append(time)

    # Create the graph with subplots
    fig = plotly.tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, vertical_spacing=0.2)
    fig['layout']['margin'] = {
        'l': 30, 'r': 10, 'b': 30, 't': 10
    }
    fig['layout']['legend'] = {'x': 0, 'y': 1, 'xanchor': 'left'}

    fig.append_trace({
        'x': data['time'],
        'y': data['Altitude'],
        'name': 'Altitude',
        'mode': 'lines+markers',
        'type': 'scatter'
    }, 1, 1)
    fig.append_trace({
        'x': data['Longitude'],
        'y': data['Latitude'],
        'text': data['time'],
        'name': 'Longitude vs Latitude',
        'mode': 'lines+markers',
        'type': 'scatter'
    }, 2, 1)
    fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        rangeselector=dict(
        buttons=list([
            dict(count=1,
                 label="1d",
                 step="day",
                 stepmode="backward")
        ])
        )
        type="date"
    )



    return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I pulled this example code from the wiki [here](https://plotly.com/python/range-slider/).

I want to automatically adjust the y-axis whenever someone clicks on the button filtering the data back to the most recent one days worth of data. To use the example "time series with range sliders and selectors" from the wiki page, I would want the y-axis to change from the default of 90 to 130 to a new value of 120 to 130.

Comment: I saw an article that said it could be done by adding the following, `fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(fixedrange=False,autorange=True),xaxis=dict(...)` but it didn't improve the situation when I introduced it. So you may have to add a custom button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `relayoutData` property of the `figure` will help here. Clicking on any button in the range selector of the figure will trigger a `relayoutData` event which we can use as input for a callback. In this callback we will change the `yaxis` range as we wish (in this example I checked if the button pressed was `1d` by performing a diff on the selected date range and checking if it is equal to `1` - if so change the range to 120-130, else bring it back to normal).
I answered with the help of the answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46519518/how-to-range-slider-and-selector-with-plotly-dash).

```
import datetime
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
import plotly
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from pyorbital.orbital import Orbital
from dateutil import parser

satellite = Orbital('TERRA')

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    html.Div([
        html.H4('TERRA Satellite Live Feed'),
        html.Div(id='live-update-text'),
        dcc.Graph(id='live-update-graph'),
        dcc.Interval(
            id='interval-component',
            interval=10*1000, # in milliseconds
            n_intervals=0
        ),
        dcc.Store(id='zoom_info')
    ])
)


@app.callback(Output('live-update-text', 'children'),
              Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'))
def update_metrics(n):
    lon, lat, alt = satellite.get_lonlatalt(datetime.datetime.now())
    style = {'padding': '5px', 'fontSize': '16px'}
    return [
        html.Span('Longitude: {0:.2f}'.format(lon), style=style),
        html.Span('Latitude: {0:.2f}'.format(lat), style=style),
        html.Span('Altitude: {0:0.2f}'.format(alt), style=style)
    ]


@app.callback(
    Output('zoom_info', 'data'),
    Input('live-update-graph', 'relayoutData')
)
def update_interval(relayout_data):
    if relayout_data is not None and f'xaxis.range[0]' in relayout_data:
        start_date = parser.parse(relayout_data['xaxis.range[0]'])
        end_date = parser.parse(relayout_data['xaxis.range[1]'])
        days_diff = (end_date - start_date).days
        if days_diff == 1:
            zoom_info = [120, 130]
        else:
            zoom_info = None
        return zoom_info
    else:
        return None


# Multiple components can update everytime interval gets fired.
@app.callback(Output('live-update-graph', 'figure'),
              Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'),
              State('zoom_info', 'data'))
def update_graph_live(n, zoom_info):
    satellite = Orbital('TERRA')
    data = {
        'time': [],
        'Latitude': [],
        'Longitude': [],
        'Altitude': []
    }

    # Collect some data
    for i in range(180):
        time = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=i*20)
        lon, lat, alt = satellite.get_lonlatalt(
            time
        )
        data['Longitude'].append(lon)
        data['Latitude'].append(lat)
        data['Altitude'].append(alt)
        data['time'].append(time)

    # Create the graph with subplots
    fig = plotly.tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, vertical_spacing=0.2)
    fig['layout']['margin'] = {
        'l': 30, 'r': 10, 'b': 30, 't': 10
    }
    fig['layout']['legend'] = {'x': 0, 'y': 1, 'xanchor': 'left'}

    fig.append_trace({
        'x': data['time'],
        'y': data['Altitude'],
        'name': 'Altitude',
        'mode': 'lines+markers',
        'type': 'scatter'
    }, 1, 1)
    fig.append_trace({
        'x': data['Longitude'],
        'y': data['Latitude'],
        'text': data['time'],
        'name': 'Longitude vs Latitude',
        'mode': 'lines+markers',
        'type': 'scatter'
    }, 2, 1)
    fig.update_layout(
        xaxis=dict(
            rangeselector=dict(
            buttons=list([
                dict(count=1,
                     label="1d",
                     step="day",
                     stepmode="backward")
            ])
            ),
            type="date")
    )
    if zoom_info:
        fig['layout'][f'yaxis']['range'] = [
            zoom_info[0],
            zoom_info[1]
        ]
    return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

- Edit - changed answer as requested by OP (include interval updates plus y-axis scaling)

Comment: Can you update this to allow for an interval update as well as the y-axis scaling? I updated my example to include the interval update

Comment: I changed the answer as you requested. Tried to help as much as I can but know that there are a few caveats. 1 - When you press on `1d` the x-axis will scale immediately but the y-axis will scale to `[120, 130]` only in the interval update (otherwise it will be much more complicated because two callbacks will need to update the graph). and 2- I implemented it only for the top subplot. Using the `xaxis2` and `yaxis2` properties of the figure you can implement it for the second subplot as well. Wish you luck and hope I helped!

Comment: Is it possible to fire an input() event when someone clicks on a updatemenu button? I want to resize the y-axis when someone clicks on an updatemenu button and it looks like relayout data does not fire

Comment: I'm not sure but you can achieve the same behaviour of an updatemenu button using a regular dash button and a callback. If you have an issue of several callbacks updating the figure you can always use `MultiplexerTransform` - https://www.dash-extensions.com/pages/transforms/multiplexer-transform