# How do I make it so that the zoom on a plotly chart stays persistent even when new data loads?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have a chart that looks like this-

```
import datetime

import dash
from dash import dcc, html
import plotly
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from pyorbital.orbital import Orbital
satellite = Orbital('TERRA')

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.layout = html.Div(
    html.Div([
        html.H4('TERRA Satellite Live Feed'),
        html.Div(id='live-update-text'),
        dcc.Graph(id='live-update-graph'),
        dcc.Interval(
            id='interval-component',
            interval=10*1000, # in milliseconds
            n_intervals=0
        )
    ])
)


@app.callback(Output('live-update-text', 'children'),
              Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'))
def update_metrics(n):
    lon, lat, alt = satellite.get_lonlatalt(datetime.datetime.now())
    style = {'padding': '5px', 'fontSize': '16px'}
    return [
        html.Span('Longitude: {0:.2f}'.format(lon), style=style),
        html.Span('Latitude: {0:.2f}'.format(lat), style=style),
        html.Span('Altitude: {0:0.2f}'.format(alt), style=style)
    ]


# Multiple components can update everytime interval gets fired.
@app.callback(Output('live-update-graph', 'figure'),
              Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'))
def update_graph_live(n):
    satellite = Orbital('TERRA')
    data = {
        'time': [],
        'Latitude': [],
        'Longitude': [],
        'Altitude': []
    }

    # Collect some data
    for i in range(180):
        time = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=i*20)
        lon, lat, alt = satellite.get_lonlatalt(
            time
        )
        data['Longitude'].append(lon)
        data['Latitude'].append(lat)
        data['Altitude'].append(alt)
        data['time'].append(time)

    # Create the graph with subplots
    fig = plotly.tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, vertical_spacing=0.2)
    fig['layout']['margin'] = {
        'l': 30, 'r': 10, 'b': 30, 't': 10
    }
    fig['layout']['legend'] = {'x': 0, 'y': 1, 'xanchor': 'left'}

    fig.append_trace({
        'x': data['time'],
        'y': data['Altitude'],
        'name': 'Altitude',
        'mode': 'lines+markers',
        'type': 'scatter'
    }, 1, 1)
    fig.append_trace({
        'x': data['Longitude'],
        'y': data['Latitude'],
        'text': data['time'],
        'name': 'Longitude vs Latitude',
        'mode': 'lines+markers',
        'type': 'scatter'
    }, 2, 1)

    return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Right now, if I zoom into the chart to look at a specific section of data and then the data refreshes, I lose my zoom position. I want to make the zoom position persistent even as new data loads. Perhaps settings the update as a background update is the answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like this should work. I added a `dcc.Store` to save the relevant zoom information for each subplot, and when reloading I read from the data of that `dcc.Store` to see if it has any historic zoom information to load from. I used this source as a guideline - https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-save-current-zoom-and-position-after-filtering/5310.

```
import datetime

import dash
from dash import dcc, html
import plotly
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from pyorbital.orbital import Orbital
satellite = Orbital('TERRA')

external_stylesheets = [
    'https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css',
    {
        'href': 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css',
        'rel': 'stylesheet',
        'integrity': 'sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO',
        'crossorigin': 'anonymous'
    }
]


app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.layout = html.Div(
    html.Div([
        html.H4('TERRA Satellite Live Feed'),
        html.Div(id='live-update-text'),
        dcc.Graph(id='live-update-graph'),
        dcc.Interval(
            id='interval-component',
            interval=10*1000, # in milliseconds
            n_intervals=0
        ),
        dcc.Store(id='zoom_info')
    ])
)


@app.callback(
    Output('zoom_info', 'data'),
    [Input('live-update-graph', 'relayoutData'),
     Input('zoom_info', 'data')]
)
def update_zoom_info(relayout_data, zoom_info):
    if zoom_info is None:
        return relayout_data
    else:
        zoom_info.update(relayout_data)
        return zoom_info


@app.callback(Output('live-update-text', 'children'),
              Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'))
def update_metrics(n):
    lon, lat, alt = satellite.get_lonlatalt(datetime.datetime.now())
    style = {'padding': '5px', 'fontSize': '16px'}
    return [
        html.Span('Longitude: {0:.2f}'.format(lon), style=style),
        html.Span('Latitude: {0:.2f}'.format(lat), style=style),
        html.Span('Altitude: {0:0.2f}'.format(alt), style=style)
    ]

# Multiple components can update everytime interval gets fired.
@app.callback(Output('live-update-graph', 'figure'),
              Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'),
              State('zoom_info', 'data'))
def update_graph_live(n, zoom_info):
    satellite = Orbital('TERRA')
    data = {
        'time': [],
        'Latitude': [],
        'Longitude': [],
        'Altitude': []
    }

    # Collect some data
    for i in range(180):
        time = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=i*20)
        lon, lat, alt = satellite.get_lonlatalt(
            time
        )
        data['Longitude'].append(lon)
        data['Latitude'].append(lat)
        data['Altitude'].append(alt)
        data['time'].append(time)

    # Create the graph with subplots
    fig = plotly.tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, vertical_spacing=0.2)
    fig['layout']['margin'] = {
        'l': 30, 'r': 10, 'b': 30, 't': 10
    }
    fig['layout']['legend'] = {'x': 0, 'y': 1, 'xanchor': 'left'}

    fig.append_trace({
        'x': data['time'],
        'y': data['Altitude'],
        'name': 'Altitude',
        'mode': 'lines+markers',
        'type': 'scatter'
    }, 1, 1)
    fig.append_trace({
        'x': data['Longitude'],
        'y': data['Latitude'],
        'text': data['time'],
        'name': 'Longitude vs Latitude',
        'mode': 'lines+markers',
        'type': 'scatter'
    }, 2, 1)

    if zoom_info:
        for axis_name in ['axis', 'axis2']:
            if f'x{axis_name}.range[0]' in zoom_info:
                fig['layout'][f'x{axis_name}']['range'] = [
                    zoom_info[f'x{axis_name}.range[0]'],
                    zoom_info[f'x{axis_name}.range[1]']
                ]
            if f'y{axis_name}.range[0]' in zoom_info:
                fig['layout'][f'y{axis_name}']['range'] = [
                    zoom_info[f'y{axis_name}.range[0]'],
                    zoom_info[f'y{axis_name}.range[1]']
                ]
    return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: This is amazing, I also wonder if uirevision = constant might work as well

Comment: Wow, I guess this could also auto-scale the y axis when someone clicks on a range selector. Is that right? I'm thinking about this one for context https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73361733/how-do-i-auto-adjust-the-y-axis-when-the-x-axis-changes-in-a-plotly-chart

Comment: Yeah you're right. Also answered your other question :) Hope it is was you were looking for.

Comment: Great answer @erap129, I have included this in my code. 

I'm just wondering how can clicking "Reset axes" or "Autoscale" (at the top-right of a graph) make `zoom_info` become `None` again. 

At the moment, when I change the zoom and filter for new data if I "Reset axes" (to zoom out) and filter for different data again, the previously selected zoom is applied.

Comment: Found a solution to my issue. Instead of `zoom_info.update(relayout_data)` in the `update_zoom_info` function, simply reassign the variable `zoom_info = relayout_data`. @erap129 is there any particular reason you chose to update instead of reassign?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answer from @erap129 and it works well, upvote.

I just wanted to add another possibility:
In my case the same behaviour (--> always keep the zoom level) could also be achieved by just adding `uirevision=True` in the `fig.update_layout(..)` area. Perhaps this is also worth a try for someone passing by here.

It is also possible to define which actions should reset the layout nonetheless, read the details here:
https://community.plotly.com/t/preserving-ui-state-like-zoom-in-dcc-graph-with-uirevision-with-dash/15793

```
# none working code snippet, just to understand where to put uirevision

fig = go.Figure(go.Densitymapbox(lat=df['lat'],
                                 lon=df['lng'],
                                 z=np.log(df['dens']),
                                 zauto=False,
                                 radius=5,
                                 opacity=0.8,
                                 colorscale='YlOrRd_r',
                                 )
               )
fig.update_layout(mapbox_style=map_chosen,
                  mapbox_zoom=zoom,
                  mapbox_center=center,
                  margin=dict(t=0, b=0, l=0, r=0),  # top bottom left right
                  uirevision=True
                 )
fig.update_traces(showscale=False)
```